# (Antenna impedance matching) How to find the load impedance

Tags: amplifier, rf, antenna, impedance-matching

I'm working on a project that requires impedance matching and I'm going to match a 50 Ω antenna to a RF amplifier SST12LP22. However, I'm not sure how can I get the impedance of the amplifier from the datasheet in order for me to design the matching circuit, or I will need to measure it?

Datasheet:
https://docs-apac.rs-online.com/webdocs/135d/0900766b8135d29f.pdf

Comment: As the MAX2235 is for 900 MHz applications you're firmly in the "RF" world. That means you need to **know what you're doing** so **know** how you would achieve an impedance match and **know** how to use a **network analyzer** to measure how good the match is. If "RF" is still "black magic" to you then I urge you to study the subject. There are plenty of good books and courses. If you just "dive in" and "do something" chances are it will end in disappointment as you have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Hi, I'm so so sorry.... I think I just copied the wrong component code. It was SST12LP22. It actually my first time touching RF field so that's why I'm abit confused.

Comment: Well, this SST12LP22 is "even worse" as it is for the 2.4 GHz band, all that I wrote in my comment still holds. There is a reason why (experienced) RF engineers are hard to find, RF it isn't something you can do without the right background and experience.

Comment: I might not an expert, an experienced engineer. I'm just trying to understand and learn so that's why I don't know why you will said so. As I know, 2.4Ghz is within the microwave range so I may I know what I've missed out?

Comment: @poppywhale please **edit** your question to fix your copy&paste error. Also add a link to the datasheet.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Also, the reason why I did this is I wanted to try out designing a broadband impedance matching circuit for antenna.

Comment: @poppywhale *I'm just trying to understand and learn* Excellent! Do you have a **Network analyzer** (for 2.5 GHz) available? The reason I ask is that generally you do not just "design" a matching network, the circuit is usually clear but the exact component values are not. You will need to **measure** and change components to **find** the correct matching network. That's needed as you do not know yet what the influence of PCB traces is. These have parasitic inductances and capacitances which influence the matching network.

Comment: But I am still on the simulation part tho. I understand these parasitic reactance will affect my matching but my concern now is the load that I'm going to use. If like you said (or at least what I understand) I am not suppose to use the SST12LP22 amplifier because its in the 2.4GHz band which mean there's no point for me to continue with the simulation if I don't change to an appropriate load right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the figures at the end of the datasheet there are some matching networks. Use those.
To get the impedances, look at the S-parameters, and you can convert those to impedances.

Based on the s-parameters in the datasheet the device is already pretty close to 50 ohm on both input and output between 2 - 3 GHz.